# Getting fenceKey null in Awareness Api

Tags: android, kotlin, google-awareness, user-activity

Hi i´m working in app that have to notificate when the user starts driving, i used Neura Api but it needs a fixed notification, so i´m trying it with Awareness Api.
I need the broadcast in the AndroidManifest.xml because i want to trigger the event even the app is not in background.
The Fence is registered fine, the broadcast is triggered but i can´t get the fenceKey and fenceStatus , i´m trying with different events for test.

**In the AndroidManifest.xml i added permissions, api key and declared the broadcast**.

```
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
         <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".usescase.receivers.FenceReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.safycab.safycab.FENCE_RECEIVER_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.awareness.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/awareness_key" />
```

**This is my FenceReceiver.kt, here is the problem when i got the event of headphones fence i try to get the fenceKey and fenceStatus but i got fenceKey = null and fenceStatus = 0**

```
class FenceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val fenceState = FenceState.extract(intent)

        context.showLocalNotification("fence key " + fenceState.fenceKey + " fence state" + fenceState.currentState)
   }
}
```

**Here is where i register the Fences, here all permissions are checked and accepted, the register is working good**

```
class FenceApiUtils(var activity: BaseActivity<*, *>) {

    var drivingFence = DetectedActivityFence.starting(DetectedActivityFence.IN_VEHICLE)

    var walkingFence = DetectedActivityFence.starting(DetectedActivityFence.ON_FOOT)

    val headPhoneFence = HeadphoneFence.during(HeadphoneState.PLUGGED_IN)

    fun createFences() {
        val intent = Intent(activity, FenceReceiver::class.java)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            activity.applicationContext, 0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        Awareness.getFenceClient(activity).updateFences(
            FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
                .addFence(VEHICLE_FENCE_KEY, drivingFence, pendingIntent)
                .addFence(WALKING_FENCE_KEY, walkingFence, pendingIntent)
                .addFence(HEADPHONE_FENCE, headPhoneFence, pendingIntent)
                .build()
        ).addOnSuccessListener {
            log("Fence was successfully registered.")
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            log("Fence could not be registered: ${it.message}")
        }
    }

}
```

**If i do this method i can check that the fence is correctly registered**

```
 fun queryFence(key: String) {
        Awareness.getFenceClient(requireActivity())
            .queryFences(FenceQueryRequest.forFences(listOf(key))).addOnSuccessListener {
                val map = it.fenceStateMap
                for (fenceKey in map.fenceKeys) {
                    val fenceState = map.getFenceState(fenceKey)
                    requireContext().showLocalNotification(
                        "Fence " + fenceKey + ": "
                                + fenceState?.currentState
                                + ", was="
                                + fenceState?.previousState
                    )
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                log(it.message)
            }
    }
```

**And if i do this i got the user activity correctly**

```
Awareness.getSnapshotClient(requireActivity()).detectedActivity.addOnSuccessListener {
                val act = it.activityRecognitionResult
                val dtc = act.mostProbableActivity
                val conf = dtc.confidence
                val activityStr = dtc.toString()
                requireContext().showLocalNotification("Activity: $activityStr, Confidence: $conf/100")
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                log(it.message)
                log(it.localizedMessage)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the pending intent flag from **FLAG_IMMUTABLE** to **FLAG_MUTABLE**:

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    activity.applicationContext, 0,
    intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
)
```

Unfortunately the documentation doesn't show how to create the mPendingIntent in https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-register, but for me this did the trick.